# How to display numpy variables in AddVisualizationCallback

Tags: drake

Currently, mathematicalprogram.AddVisualizationCallback only supports Mathematical Program Variables for visualization. This makes it hard to visualize numpy arrays (we could possibly use global variables inside the callback function but this adds a lot of unnecessary code).

Is there any other way to display the numpy variables? Or can we just open up AddVisualizationCallback to support more arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a lambda function that captures your numpy array?

```py
v = prog.NewContinuousVariables(3)
my_numpy_array = np.array([1, 2, 3])

def callback(prog_vars, my_numpy_array):
    # Do something

# The visualization can depend on just a subset of program variables, as vars=v[:2] in this example.
prog.AddVisualizationCallback(lambda x : callback(x, my_numpy_array), vars=v[:2])
```

Comment: This kind of works. But it still requires you to pass in your full set of np object / Variables inside x everytime.

Comment: @user3180 Sorry I don't get what you mean. In the example code above, `x` is the variables that you are interested in visualizing in each iteration of the optimization. `x` doesn't need to be all the variables in your optimization. I updated my example code above to reflect this.